# JsonSchema.Validate() ObjectExpected: #/myField

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate some json using the JSON.Net Schema support for validation. The JSON has a field called extra which is optional - sometimes it will be supplied with null. I'm trying the following code:

```
var json = "{ \"id\": 1, \"extra\": null }";

var schema = new JsonSchema4();
var extraProp = new JsonProperty {
    Type = JsonObjectType.Object,
    IsRequired = false
};

schema.Properties.Add( "extra", extraProp );

schema.Validate(json);
```

And am receiving the following validation error:

```
ObjectExpected: #/extra
```

How can I set the schema up to tolerate the "extra" field being null sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the field from the JSON altogether, it validates. Setting it to null is not sufficient.

var json = "{ \"id\": 1 }";

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the `Type` for the extraProp as `Object` it will not allow null value.
If you want to allow null then you can use oneOf to do so.
Define `extraProp` as below and it should allow nulls.

```
var extraProp = new JsonProperty();
extraProp.OneOf.Add(new JsonSchema4(){Type = JsonObjectType.Null});
extraProp.OneOf.Add(new JsonSchema4(){Type = JsonObjectType.Object});
```

Also you can check if your propery definition allows nulls as follow

```
Console.Write(extraProp.IsNullable(NullHandling.JsonSchema));
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if you need anything else.